# Get option value for mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the value from the option selected by the select box to MySQL where i want to use it as a condition for this

```
update med set stock = stock - 1 where id_med =  xxx
```

i want the xxx to be the one the user selects from the select box like below:

```
<td>                                            
   <select name="buku">                                         
      <option  value="1">Paracetamol</option>
      <option  value="2">Ibuprofen</option>
      </select>
<td>
```

also, the select box is on another .php file

Comment: This is only HTML and SQL. You also need to code your backend in PHP.

Comment: @Dharman it is in php, i only take a bit of the code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have make two files for this. One which contains the HTML code. And another that contains PHP code.

The code in select tag would be within a form.

So your HTML code should be like

```html
<form action="target.php" method="post">
<table>
<td>                                            
   <select name="buku">                                         
      <option  value="1">Paracetamol</option>
      <option  value="2">Ibuprofen</option>
      </select>
<td>
</table>
</form>
```

Now you will require a PHP code that can execute the query for you.

```html
<?php

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","your_username","your_password","your_dbname");

if(isset($_POST['buku']))
{
$item = $_POST['buku'];
$query = "update med set stock = stock - 1 where id_med ='$item'";

mysqli_query($conn,$query);

echo <<<_END
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=source_url.extension'>
_END;
}
?>
```

Please note this code is only for learning purpose. Don't use it in a production environment.

Comment: Well then you are teaching them how to shot themselves in the leg. If you want to teach them, show them a correct code.

Comment: I gave both alternatives. PDO and MySQLi. My point was not that you should switch to PDO(which is easier), but that you should use prepared statements! If the user can't understand PHP then what you are teaching them will not help them understand it, but rather cause more confusion. Prepared statements are simpler and less messy.

Comment: If I pull a trigger while holding gun to my head I am sure it will work too, but I would not want to do that. Even if you code works for `buku=hi` it will not work for `buku=h'i`

Comment: Well the user only accepted what he was looking for

Comment: @BryanJoshua Beware of this code. It might work for simple strings, but it is ultimately broken and very unsecure. Do not use it! You need to look into prepared statements and NEVER insert PHP variables into SQL queries.

Comment: @Dharman its not going online, its for a homework for my varsity

Comment: Your homework might not be graded very well. Let me point this out again: this code is broken, it will not work all the time. If you have tried something already, [edit and put your PHP code in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57006400/edit), maybe I can help you fix it fully.

Comment: @Dharman i just got enrolled, we're not that deep yet into the subject. its okay

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into PHP Post and Get requests and also wrapping your inputs in a `<form>` tag.

If configured correctly, an element of $_GET or $_POST will be created with the name of `buku` in this case and its value will be stored as `1` or `2` depending on the value of what you've put in the `value` attribute.

You can learn more about PHP form handling here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: you should try to explain here instead of the link. because in future what if link is broken